# Launch winform with webrowser url from separate application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

essentially what I want to do is I have one .exe .net program I made with a button in it. I want the click event in that button to launch my second .exe file, and change the WebBrowser URL in that second application. Is this possible?

The urls will be html pages on my computer.

Comment: What do you mean by a Winforms Browser Application?

Comment: well...guess the way I would describe it is that I created a .exe file that is basically just a .net winform with a browser window in it.  WIth a separate .exe file, I want to control the url.

Comment: You can run a normal windows application from a url. But it's not related to the `WebBrower` control which you hosted in the form. The job of the `WebBrowser` control is showing `Html` content, it may be an offline or an online html content.

Comment: essentially what I want to do is I have one .exe .net program I made with a button in it.  I want the click event in that button to launch my second .exe file, and change the WebBrowser URL in that second application

Comment: It's a better description, you should edit the question and add it to the question. and say what url do you want to set for `WebBrowser` Control.

Comment: updated accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: You can run your second application passing a command line argument (the url you want to use) and then, in the second application, set the url as `Url` of `WebBrowser` control

Comment: Also please add language tag to your question. for example C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to **share some data** between 2 programs, one way to do it:

```
private void btnLaunchBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string yourExePath = "WhateverIsThePath.exe";
    string url = "YourLocalUrlHere";
    var browserWinformsApp = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(yourExePath, url);
    // Here you can control over the second Process, you can even 
    // Force it to Close by browserWinformsApp.Close();
}
```

In your Second App (Browser one), update `Program.cs` to accept `parameters`:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        string passedUrl = args[0];
        Application.Run(new Form1(passedUrl));
    }
}
```

Finally, update your `Form's` constructor to accept a `string` `url`:

```
private string browserUrl;
public Form1(string url)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browserUrl= url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much